# Adding Line Breaks in QR Code / 2D Barcode

Tags: barcode

In Windows 10, I am using qrencode for printing QR codes to image files. The printing is successful but I am stuck at adding line breaks. I have tried the below method with no success in line breaks.

Windows Command Prompt:
`d:\ qrencode -o qrcode.png "INDO GERMAN ALKALOIDS  \nUnique ID: ABC-123456789  \nAPI-Name: ABCDEFGH  \nBrand: Indo-101 \nAddress: Inga House, Mahakali Road, Andheri-East, Mumbai-400093, \nTel-022-28202932/33, \nMobile: 9833942075, \nBatch No.: XYZ888999000, \nBatch Size: 1020, \nMfgd.Date: 29-12-2022, \nExpiry Date: 31-12-2023, \nContainer Code: RRR-101020, \nMfgr Lic.No.: ------------, \nStorage Instruction: Store in cool area 20deg"`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for some time, I came across the below command in the Ubuntu Manuals:
`cat bigfile.txt | qrencode -S -v 40 -l L -o output.png`

I placed the required content as below in a text file named qr-data.txt

INDO GERMAN ALKALOIDS

Unique ID: ABC-123456789

API-Name: ABCDEFGH

Brand: Indo-101

Then at the DOS prompt I typed:
`type qr-data.txt | qrencode -o qr-code.png`

It now works perfect for me.

Note that I used [type] instead of [cat] in MS DOS.